# No encuentro porqué ClassLoader.getResource() retorna null aunque el archivo si existe en classpath

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, jboss

Empiezo aclarando que durante ya unos días vengo leyendo otras preguntas similares, tanto aqui como en otros foros, pero el origen del problema no era el mismo que tengo yo y no me ayudaron mucho. (Por ejemplo estas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450865/thread-currentthread-getcontextclassloader-getresourceasstream-return-nul, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020350/thread-currentthread-getcontextclassloader-getresourceasstream-returns-nul, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111484/usage-of-thread-currentthread-getcontextclassloader-getresourceasstreamsys). Y si consideran que la pregunta no está clara, por favor, indicarme como podría mejorarla. Pero realmente necesito ayuda :(

Mi meta es **acceder al contenido de un archivo .xml**, ubicado en una carpeta dentro de WEB-INF en mi proyecto. Debido a que la ruta del proyecto puede cambiar, es necesario acceder al archivo mediante getResource().

Les comparto la estructura de paquetes del proyecto y la configuración del BuildPath:

[image: Files structure]

Esta es la manera como intento acceder a los archivos dentro de WEB-INF/directory desde la clase Parser:

```
public NodeList obtenerCamposXML(String fileName, String tipo)throws Exception{
        NodeList camposXML = null;
        try {
            final String resourcePath = "WEB-INF/directory/"+fileName+".xml";
            URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourcePath);
            File f = new File(url.getFile());
            //more code here...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("No se encuentra el archivo XML");
            throw e;
        }
        return camposXML;
    }
```

El valor de **la variable url siempre retorna null**. Sin embargo, el archivo si existe en la ruta indicada, por lo que creo que me falta alguna configuración para que **la ruta del WEB-INF se cargue como recurso** corretamente. Por favor, agradecería mucho alguna sugerencia o que me ayuden a identificar que estoy haciendo mal.

PD. Hay una carpeta resources en src/main/java que no debe ser alterada. De igual manera, la capeta WEB-INF debe permanecer dentro de webapp.

PD2. No creo que el código esté mal, pues anteriormente estuvo desplegado en WAS sin problemas. Yo estoy intentando desplegarlo en Jboss 7.2 y falla en tiempo de ejecución al no encontrar el archivo.

Gracias por su apoyo! :)

Comment: ¿Has usado el método exists() para comprobar si existe el archivo? Podrías mostrar en pantalla toda la ruta del archivo a leer.  ``if (file.exists() == true){ System.out.println("Ruta absoluta: "+file.getAbsolutePath())  }``

Comment: Como el valor de la variable url se queda en null, la línea `File f = new File(url.getFile());` genera nullPointerException. Por lo tanto, no puedo validar si el archivo existe o no mediante código. Sin embargo, los archivos si existen, son los .xml que he resaltado en la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que no podía acceder a los archivos .xml era porque la carpeta `WEB-INF/directory` no estaba siendo integrada dentro del **classpath** al compilar, por lo que el método getResource() no la encontraba y retornaba null.

Para poder **identificar que carpetas está consideradas dentro del classpath** se puede ejecutar la siguiente línea:

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Esta es otra alternativa:

```
final File classPathFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

Recorriendo los archivos dentro de esa ruta se puede validar si la carpeta/archivos a los que deseamos acceder están incluidos en el classpath.

En mi caso, **la carpeta WEB-INF no estaba incluida**, por lo que debía definirla como  en el **pom.xml** para que sea incluida en el classpath:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <webResource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/directory</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/directory</targetPath>
            </webResource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Luego de hacer esta modificación, logré acceder a los archivos mediante getResource().

Más detalle de como incluir archivos/carpetas en classpath en el sgt link: [Apache - Adding and Filtering External Web Resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

Answer (score 1):

Si lanza `null` definitivamente es porque no está apuntando apropiadamente al `.xml`; entonces ya sabiendo que el recurso está en `WEB-INF` debes modificar la ruta de `resourcePath`.

Supongamos que cuentas con el archivo alojado directamente en `WEB-INF`, la ruta debe ser:

```
resourcePath="../"+fileName+".xml";
```

Ahora si el `xml` está en `WEB-INF/directory` se cambia lógicamente a:

```
resourcePath="../directory/"+fileName+".xml";
```